# Can you access browser memory dump in Javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, sha256

I know it has been asked before. But I am yet not sure about the solution(whether it is at all possible).

In firefox, even in IE, if I login to gmail, and take the memory dump of the browser process, password is clearly visible in plain text.

Though this does not happen at all for chrome.

So, was just wondering can we at all, at least hash(using salted has) or remove the password from browser memory dump in javascript for our website?

Comment: If someone has access to a browser memory dump to get hold of a password, they have access to do much more nefarious things on the computer.  This isn't a risk you can protect yourself from as a website - the issue here is entirely on the end user.